# Пытаюсь перевести игру на pygame в exe файл . Но есть проблема с импортом картинок и звуков

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

Искал долго информацию , как перевести игру в exe . Пытался перевести файл.py в spec и редактировать его , добавляя путь до картинок в нем. Так же менял путь до картинок и в самом коде игры через модули os и sys. Но exe файл так и не создается корректно , из-за чего игра сразу выключается на стадии запуска.

Comment: Попробуйте сам py файл конвертировать в exe с помощью pyinstaller.Пути пропишите: "Data/ имя файла" .У вас появится папка с именем вашего py файла . А потом в эту папку закиньте папку(название: Data) с вашими аудио и картинками. И можете показать, как вы пишете пути к файлу(все варианты).

Comment: Использовал информацию с этого сайта https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/143934/.   Понял , почему не правильно создавался exe . Картинки импортируются нормально, а звуки нет . На чтении звуках программа обрывается

Comment: Если  вас файлы лежат в папке где лежит ваш py файл, то попробуйте так: image = pygae.load('Имя файла').Я думаю, что способ на хабре слишком сложный и может из-за этого картинки и не загружаются.Только после этого вы должны картинки перенести в папку с конвертированным py файлом